# how to concatenate matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have n dxd matrices in Matlab and I want to concatenate them to get a dxdxn matrix where (:,:,i) is the i^th matrix (i=1..n). How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [CAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cat.html)

```
out = cat(3,mat1,mat2,mat3,...,matN);
```

If the arrays are elements of a cell array,

```
out = cat(3,cellArray{:});
```